# Label hover width to go full width of the div

Tags: html, css

I want the hover background to stretch all the way from border to border of the div and not just wrap the word

```
<div id="selection">    
       <label class="category_label"><input type="checkbox">abc</label><br>
       <label class="category_label"><input type="checkbox">d</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#selection{
    padding:0.5em;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background: white;
}
label.category_label{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
}
label.category_label:hover{
    background:#ccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2H2tr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/vahidseo/2H2tr/3/

Delete that br tag.

Change this:

```
label.category_label{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: perfect! ill accept it as an answer when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

One thing You can do is set label styles to

```
display:block;
```

remove "br" tag, then, on hover You just set label to

```
width:100%;
```

and thats it :-)
updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2H2tr/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
label.category_label{
cursor:pointer;
width:100%;
float:left;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2H2tr/4/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each of the label elements in a `div` (which is *designed* to have `display: block;`) and give that the hover rule:

```
div.wrapper:hover {
    background: #ccc
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcLs6/1/)